# How can I push from local to root directory in remote repository

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I initialized wrong directory. How can I push my files to root directory

Here is how my remote folder looks like

```
/myproject
  /public
  /src
```

how can i push and move all files in /public, /src and other files to the top level and the delete 'myproject'

Comment: Move them around (using whatever file explorer you use) and commit the changes.

Answer (score 0):

This question is unclear !

We could usually re initialize the repository on a new directory.

As you have already initialized the repository outside of /myproject, try git init inside /myproject folder. if that shows an error, you may need to remove the pre initialized repository.

you can do this by `rm -rf .git` in bash. (this removes all git features from the specified folder).

after you can `git init` iniside /myproject and commit !

Be sure to know what you're doing, this action may case loss of data !